# How to use lemmatization with the stanza library with dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, stanford-nlp

My current database is:

```
# bibliotecas necessárias
import pandas as pd

dict_noticia = {'nome_adm': ['CC Brasil', 
                           'ABC Futuro Esporte',
                           'Tabuao'], 
              
              'noticia': ["['folha', 'paulo', 'https', 'east', 'amazonaws', 'multclipp', 'arquivos', 'noticias', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'mônica', 'bergamo', 'longo', 'tempo']", 
                   "['coluna', 'estadão']",
                   "['flamengo', 'futebol','melhor','campeao','é']"]
                   }
                   
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_noticia)
df
```

I need a new column with the lemmas of the "news" column.
The script below gives error:

```
import stanza
nlp_stanza = stanza.Pipeline(lang='pt', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')

def f_lematizacao_stanza(df,column_name,new_column_name):
    df[new_column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: ([w.lemma_ for w in nlp_stanza(row)]))
    return df

f_lematizacao_stanza(data,'noticia','noticia_lema')
```

NameError: name 'row' is not defined

How to solve

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to replace `nlp_stanza(row)` for `nlp_stanza(x)`.

Comment: As the error says, your script is using a variable named "row" which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the variable `row`. You need to use `x`:

```
def f_lematizacao_stanza(df,column_name,new_column_name):
    df[new_column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: ([w.lemma_ for w in nlp_stanza(x)]))
    return df
```